Setting up network manually, no dhcp, IPV4 only
I’m trying to configure ip (static, so without dhcp), there are some problems that I can't resolve by my self, because I do not understand it in a whole. Sorry if it is already answered, but as I said, I can't find any topic explaining it in a whole.
I'm using wpa_supplicant to connect, on a system with openRC as service manager.
Here are what I did yet :
DNS resolution : /etc/resolve.conf
nameserver 172.20.10.1
Host name : /etc/hosts
192.168.1.150 myname.name.net
Interfaces : /etc/network/interfaces
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.150
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 

-ip a(ddress) : gives me an ip for the interface wlan0, but no netmask, not gateway.
-arp : ? (192.168.1.1) at <incomplete> on wlan0
-ip r(oute) default 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 metric 1 onlink 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.150
With this, I can't connect to a routeur, but looks like I can only send packets, ping stackoverflow.com returns error.
My questions are :

Why arp is incomplete, and how to fixe it ?
Why ip a doesn't print netsmak and gateway for device wlan0 ?
What's the use of netmask and gateway ?

Thanks to anyone who takes time to answer to an apprentice.

Check router. My old routers only use DHCP on a range of addresses. So you set a fixed outside of that range. My newer router uses DHCP on all addresses. And you have to change settings in router to exclude DHCP. Check router manual as it varies by brand. Are you not able to log into 192.168.1.1


Why arp is incomplete, and how to fixe it ?

It means your computer hasn't received an ARP response.
Why it hasn't received an ARP response (or why you're unable to receive packets) is a different question.

You should first be checking whether wpa_supplicant has successfully associated to the Wi-Fi network – that's the Wi-Fi equivalent of checking the cable; if it has not connected then IP configuration is kinda moot.

Then make sure the address of the gateway is actually correct for the Wi-Fi network you're connected to. (If you have more than one SSID configured then static IP configuration is really unwise.)



Why ip a doesn't print netsmak and gateway for device wlan0 ?

It does print the netmask, but in CIDR format – 255.255.255.0 is printed as /24 next to the address. (The netmask has 24 "1" bits.)
The gateway, meanwhile, is not a property associated with your address configuration. Instead it directly goes into your routing table and is shown by ip r.

What's the use of netmask and gateway ?

The "netmask" parameter generates a local subnet route based on your address – the 192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 route in your case. It tells the OS which IP addresses are reachable directly on the local network (via their MAC addresses), i.e. without needing to route through a gateway.
The "gateway" parameter generates a default route – the 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.1.1 route in your case. It's used to reach IP addresses that are not directly reachable (i.e. everything that the aforementioned local subnet route doesn't cover) – since there's no direct MAC address, the host sends packets to the gateway's MAC address instead.
